# Next.JS - Error when Checking if window == undefined : Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am getting the following error:

> Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

I am using `getServerSideProps` and in my page, I check whether we are in the browser (`window=='undefined'`), and then return things accordingly:

```
export default function Page() {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  if (typeof window == 'undefined') return null

  if (session) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Protected Page</h1>
        <p>You can view this page because you are signed in.</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
  return <p>Access Denied</p>
}
```

But this line here

```
if (typeof window == 'undefined') return null
```

seems to be the problem. When this line is commented out, everything works.

It's also true that what's returned on the server side will be different to whats' returned on the client side - but I don't fully understand how I should solve this problem and why this is a problem?

I am doing this check *precisely because I only want to render this page on the client side* -side & when I do have a session. Am I misunderstanding this?

Answer (score 2):

The point of SSR is to prerender the page on the server. If on the server your page renders always `null` there's no need to use SSR.

If you want to prerender the page only if a session exists, then you have to check the session on the server, inside of `getServerSideProps`.

If you check the session inside of the page component, the check is done on the client, and again there would be no need to use `getServerSideProps`.

Here is an example took from one of my projects, in which I used [NextAuth](https://next-auth.js.org/) to manage authentication:

```
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client';

// ...your page component here...

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const session = await getSession({ req: context.req });

  if (session) {
    return { props: { session } };
  }
  else {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/auth',
        permanent: false,
      }
    };
  }
}
```

In this snippet the session is checked on the server.
If a session exists it will accessible in the page component via its `props`.
If the session doesn't exist, the user is redirected to the authentication page.

PS: I just checked [the docs](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#server-side-example) and it looks like the import has changed to `'next-auth/react'` (which, by the way, make more sense as using `/client` on the server is misleading).

Comment: Just a note that the recommended function to use currently seems to be `unstable_getServerSession()` as per [the docs](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#server-side)